# Missed scanf and function goes on without it. If I add a space still doesn't work

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, printf, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct mychar {
    char value;
    struct mychar *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct mychar Mychar;


void instructions();
void append(Mychar **, char );
void printlist(Mychar *);


int main(){
    instructions();

    Mychar *startPtr = NULL;

    unsigned int choice;
    char newchar;
    do {
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                printf("\nWrite the character you want to add.");
                printf("\n> ");
                scanf(" %c", &newchar);
                append(&startPtr, newchar);
                printlist(startPtr);
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            default:
                printf("\nError, try again.\n");
                //main();
                instructions();
                break;
        }
    } while (choice!=3);
    printf("\n\nEnd of run.\n");
}


void instructions(){
    printf("\nSelect operation. 1 to add, 2 to remove, 3 to exit.");
    printf("\n> ");
}


void append(Mychar **sPtr, char newvalue){
    Mychar *newlinkPtr = calloc (1, sizeof(Mychar));
    newlinkPtr->value = newvalue;
    newlinkPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    Mychar *previousPtr = NULL;
    Mychar *currentPtr = *sPtr;

    while(currentPtr!=NULL && newvalue > currentPtr->value){
        previousPtr = currentPtr;
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    if (previousPtr){
        previousPtr->nextPtr = newlinkPtr;
        newlinkPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
    } else {
        *sPtr = newlinkPtr;
    }

}


void printlist(Mychar *currentPtr){
    printf("\n\nCurrent list:\n");
    while (currentPtr!=NULL){
        printf("%c", currentPtr->value);
        currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
    }
}
```

Why do I have this behaviour? If I run the program, after I enter 1, it  prints the "current list" and leave the scanf input opened, so I can enter the value only after "current list" printed. Also, "current list" should be called only after I enter the character with scanf, since the function printlist is AFTER the scanf... but actually this is what happens:

```
Select operation. 1 to add, 2 to remove, 3 to exit.
> 1

Write the character you want to add.
> a


Current list:
ab

Write the character you want to add.
> 

Current list:
abc

Write the character you want to add.
> 

Current list:
abcd

Write the character you want to add.
> 

Current list:
abcd
```

Comment: @user3121023 I think you didn't read the thread :(

Comment: Something in `append()` is probably causing undefined behavior and corrupting the heap.

Comment: I suggest you step through `append()` in the debugger and make sure it's working as intended.

Comment: I think `while(*sPtr!=NULL && newvalue > currentPtr->value){` should be `while(currentPtr!=NULL && newvalue > currentPtr->value){`

Comment: This must be one of the most FAQ here, probably several times a day. Please change `scanf("%c", &newchar);` to `scanf(" %c", &newchar);` with an added space. Please see [scanf() leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer). Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[...]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too.

Comment: @WeatherVane I think you didn't read all the thread.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62071579/scanf-makes-do-while-loop-stuck

Comment: You've got more than one bug. The first bug is in the `scanf("%c", ...)`. You need a space, as you already know. To test that the `scanf` is working correctly, remove the calls to `append` and `printlist`, and instead `printf("The character is '%c'\n", newchar)` Once you've got that working, you can move on to the next bug.

Comment: @Barmar yeah, replacing it now I finally gets the printed list, but there still are the same problems of the thread.

Comment: @mlp you didn't read all the thread.

Comment: @Mnkisd the question title "Missed scanf and function goes on without it" and in the narrative "it doesn't let me enter any character... It only prints the current list" is a typical result. If the program carries on and faults, that's another issue.

Comment: Your real problem is with the segmentation fault. Why don't you fix the scanf in the posted code, and fix the title, so people will stop trying to close it as a duplicate of the `space-%c` answer.

Comment: @Barmar there isn't a seg fault anymore, I fixed it. I also updated the thread.

Comment: @Mnkisd You updated the code but it is still missing the space before %c, to do what you want that is necessary, not an option.

Comment: @isrnick ok, done it.

Comment: So has it, or hasn't it cured the segfault? If it has, was that a red herring from an undefined input?

Comment: @WeatherVane it did. but not the printf/scanf problem

Comment: @Mnkisd add a `printf("\n");` at the end of the `printlist` funcion and a call to `instructions()` before the scanf or at the end of do-while loop, the problem is that you are not being prompted to type a new number.

Comment: @isrnick this fixed the problem... but even if now works I ask to myself... why it continued to print `Write the character you want to add.` like if the switch loop was like "stuck" in case 1 ?

Comment: ...because [`scanf()` leaves the newline char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer), as mentioned, which was taken as its input, and anything else you typed also remained in the input buffer, and if it was a character that can't be processed by `%d` then it sticks there.

Comment: @Mnkisd because as you were not asked to type a number you were actually typing a letter in the scanf with %d , so the scanf failed and the program continued without changing the value of the variable `choice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lesson to take form this is to always check `scanf` for `0` return, at the very least, `EOF` check is also advised, and act accordingly, as for the order of events of your code, it's not quite there, with some tweaks you can have a nice, bad input proof, I/O sequence:

```
void clear_stdin() { //stdin buffer clearing function 
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF){}
}
```

```
do {
    instructions(); //move inside the loop, user will be prompted in each cycle
    while (scanf("%d", &choice) == 0) {
        printf("\nError, try again.\n");
        instructions();
        clear_stdin(); // if input fails clear the buffer
    }
    clear_stdin(); // clear the buffer for 1hjh type input
    switch (choice) {
    case 1:

        printf("\nWrite the character you want to add.");
        printf("\n> ");
        while (scanf(" %c", &newchar) == 0) { //this can be a pattern
            clear_stdin();                    //see @ismick comment
        }                                     //
        clear_stdin();                        //
        append(&startPtr, newchar);
        printlist(startPtr);
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    case 3:
        printf("\n\nEnd of run.\n"); //if you dont have a case default will catch 3
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nError, try again.\n");
        break;
    }
} while (choice != 3);
```

Comment: There is still a chance that the user could type bad input in the first `scanf`... Something like `1abc` typed in the first `scanf` would be accepted but would end up skipping the second `scanf`.

Comment: @isrnick, yes well spotted, will add the first caught character to the list, a clearence at the beginning of the case should fix it.

Comment: At this point a `clear()` function with the clearence routine would be appropriate

Comment: Yes, I would call it `clearstdin()` for clarity. Also instead of `if(scanf...` you could use `while(scanf...` so it doesn't continue to the next steps while a valid input isn't typed.

Comment: @isrnick, the while is also a good adition, I guess we're 99% bullet proof now. ;)

Comment: I noticed you placed the `clear_stdin()` at the beginning of `case 1:`, and at the end of the `do-while` loop. Why not place it after each `while (scanf) {clear_stdin}` instead? So that it becomes a pattern `while (scanf) {clear_stdin} clear_stdin` that can be re-used whenever you use the `scanf` function.

Comment: @isrnick, yes that can be done, it's a good solution, I wsn't going for perfection but now we're near. I would make the routines but maybe that's too much

Comment: @anastaciu thanks for answer. 2 questions: 1) why do you put `clear_stdin()` even after the `while(scanf)` part? Why is it needed?  2) what's the difference between using your `clear_stdin()` and using `fflush(stdin)` ?

Comment: @Mnkisd `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behaviour, the `fflush` function is only meant to be used for output streams, but `stdin` is an input stream, so despite it working to clear `stdin` in some system or compiler it is also as likely to fail or do something totally unexpected in another.

Comment: @Mnkisd, 1) It's basically input checking, consider this, if you type something like `1hhjk` in option selection, 1 will be parsed succefully, scanf will return 1 and `hhjk` will remain on the buffer being caught by the next scanfs. The same happens with the characters input, if you type `asdfsd`, only `a` will be parsed, so we need to clear the rest. As for 2) [ismick just answered it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62072901/why-does-my-append-function-cause-a-segfault/62074708?noredirect=1#comment109805931_62074708). More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247021/6865932)

Comment: @Mnkisd the `clear_stdin()` is there after the `while(scanf)` loop to clear anything left in the `stdin` after the `scanf` read succeeds, remember that `scanf` leaves the new line character in the `stdin`, and also that the user may type bad input that is successfully read by `scanf`, for example a `scanf` with `%d` would have no problem reading 1 when the user types `1abc`, so in this case it would be necessary to clear the `abc` plus new line characters left in the `stdin`.

Comment: @anastaciu what could I do to clear stdin from strings or ints instead of char? Can I use your clear_stdin() function as well? Also, why did you put != '\n' ?

Comment: @Mnkisd, yes, the function clears whatever is in the buffer.

Comment: @anastaciu why did you put != '\n' ?

Comment: @Mnkisd, when you press enter a `\n` character is added to the buffer, so you know when it is consumed by `getchar()` there are no more characters in there. Reading cycle literaly: while the consumed character is different from `\n` read the next one.